# Unencrypted "VPN-like" tunnel?

Tags: networking, router, vpn, tunnel

I would like to set up a persistent tunnel between my home router and a remote server, which would allow me to maintain a static IP address and perform port-forwarding (my router is currently behind another, unmanaged router).

Setting up an ordinary VPN would be easy enough, but I would like to avoid the overhead of encryption if possible. The purpose of this tunnel is not for any kind of privacy; it's just to give me more control over my ordinary internet traffic. I'm also not concerned about man in the middle or other attack vectors, for the same reasons.

Are there any options for such a tunnel with basic authentication but otherwise unencrypted traffic for maximum performance?

Comment: That is correct, which is why I specified "VPN-like", in the sense that it would create a direct tunnel between the two machines. I have heard of technologies such as GRE and L2TP which are unencrypted by themselves; however there aren't many resources online on whether it is feasible to use one without an accompanying encryption protocol, so I thought I would ask about it here.

Comment: @Ramhound On the other hand, if we implemented *Virtual Public Network* somehow, the abbreviation would be… VPN. :)

Comment: @Ramhound: That's a rather recent redefinition of "VPN" – just a while ago, 'private' merely meant tunnelled access _to_ a non-public network (i.e. a LAN) rather than any sort of encryption. (For example, PPTP didn't have _any_ for quite some time.)

Comment: It sounds kind of like you want to make this remote server your new gateway, maybe with `route` on linux. I'm not sure about the remote part, or the authentication

Comment: @Xen2050, that's the idea, yes. But the problem with simply adding it as a route is that that doesn't provide me with the ability to initiate connections from outside my home router. I want to be able to port forward from the remote server to my router, which will require a tunnel since my router is behind another NAT router which I do not control (internet provided by apt complex).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can configure [OpenVPN](https://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source.html) to disable encryption completely using the [configuration options](https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/Openvpn24ManPage):

> **--cipher alg**
>
> > To see other ciphers that are available with OpenVPN, use the --show-ciphers option.
> >
> > Set alg=none to disable encryption.
> >
> > As of OpenVPN 2.4, cipher negotiation (NCP) can override the cipher specified by --cipher. See --ncp-ciphers and --ncp-disable for more on NCP.
>
> **--ncp-disable**
>
> > Disable "negotiable crypto parameters". This completely disables cipher negotiation.

The real question is why would you disable the encryption?  Its actually more work to disable the encryption versus using the OpenVPN defaults.  I would set it up in the default configuration, and only disable the encryption if you have actual data that points to the encryption causing performance or other issues.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. My motivation is to reduce the significant bandwidth overhead, as well as the additional processing time on both ends, which is introduced by encryption. I believe these issues are predictable just based on the nature of E2EE.

Comment: You should do some measuring to see the actual overhead of the encryption.

Comment: @ParkerKemp I agree with Joe, encryption typically also involves compression, so you may actually end up using less bandwidth, and my guess is that unless you have a very heavy load, the processing overhead will be minimal, but you can't know anything until you have measured.

Comment: You make a good argument in terms of bandwidth. I am still concerned with the processing requirements, since I plan to use a home router as one of the endpoints. I don't know too much about the computing capabilities of the average Netgear router, but I would be surprised if it could decompress and decrypt data at 100Mb/s, which is my connection speed. At your recommendation, I will measure the results and see if my concern is valid. Thanks for the tip about using OpenVPN unencrypted.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively to OpenVPN, a tunnel without encryption can be configured with the L2TP protocol if both devices provide support.

For example, if both home router and remote server run on Linux kernels and provide the [iproute2](https://wiki.linuxfoundation.org/networking/iproute2) utilities suite, the L2TP tunnel can be setup via the [ip-l2tp](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ip-l2tp.8.html) command, as per example below.

On the home router:

```
[root@homeRouter]# ip l2tp add tunnel \
    tunnel_id 1 peer_tunnel_id 1 \
    local ${homeRouterAddr} remote ${remoteServerAddr} \
    encap udp udp_sport 1701 udp_dport 1701

[root@homeRouter]# ip l2tp add session \
    tunnel_id 1 peer_tunnel_id 1 name l2tp0 \
    session_id 1 peer_session_id 1 seq both

[root@homeRouter]# ip link set dev l2tp0 up

[root@homeRouter]# ip addr add dev l2tp0 172.16.24.33/30
```

On the remote server:

```
[root@remoteServer]# ip l2tp add tunnel \
    tunnel_id 1 peer_tunnel_id 1 \
    local ${remoteServerAddr} remote ${homeRouterAddr} \
    encap udp udp_sport 1701 udp_dport 1701

[root@remoteServer]# ip l2tp add session \
    tunnel_id 1 peer_tunnel_id 1 name l2tp0 \
    session_id 1 peer_session_id 1 seq both

[root@remoteServer]# ip link set dev l2tp0 up

[root@remoteServer]# ip addr add dev l2tp0 172.16.24.34/30
```

On the example above, the devices will communicate to each other under the 172.16.24.32/30 subnet.

Also, on the example above, the L2TP packets are being encapsulated by UDP packets. For increased performance and if network firewalls on the path allow so, the L2TP packets can be directly encapsulated by IP packets, as well.

Basic authentication between the endpoints can be configured by supplying a valid `cookie` argument to the `ip l2tp add session` command lines.

The configuration can be made persistent via startup configuration, such as custom systemd units.